# Не видит классы autoload.php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, composer

Вчера ВК выпустили `PHP SDK` для взаимодействия со своим `API`. 

Зашел в документацию и увидел, что библиотеку надо ставить через `composer`.

Композером пользовался один раз, когда ставил Yii.

Запускаю `OpenServer` (так сайт на локалке), включаю консоль, запускаю `composer`.

Зашел в директорию своего сайта(`cd domains/mysite`). Перед установкой обновил композер командой:`composer selfupdate`, он обновился и следом ставлю библиотеку командой: `composer require vkcom/vk-php-sdk`. 

Все установилось, но когда подключил `autoload.php` и инициализировал класс `$vk = new VKApiClient();`, выдало ошибку, что класс не найден.

Вопрос: В чем может быть ошибка ?

Код ошибки:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VKApiClient' not found in C:\WebServer\domains\mysite\backend\include\query.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\WebServer\domains\mysite\admin\index.php(4): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\WebServer\domains\mysite\backend\include\query.php on line 4
```

SDK который использовал: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk

Comment: Попробуй сделать "composer dump-autoload"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создавайте объект либо так

```
$vk = new \VK\Client\VKApiClient();
```

Либо в начале файла

```
use VK\Client\VKApiClient;
```

а потом уже как и пробовали

```
$vk = new VKApiClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте наличие в composer.json наличие установленной библиотеки. Можно загрузку вручную прописать, например так:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "VK\\": "vkcom/vk-php-sdk"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно класс находится в другом неймспейсе. Попробуйте использовать $vk = new \VKApiClient();
И не плохо было бы указать, что за сдк используете (ссылку на него) и еще раз посмотреть доки)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил с

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method VK\Client\VKApiClient::request()
```

Добавил в файл VKApiClient.php в 270й строке:

```
public function request(): VKApiRequest {
         return $this->request;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Убедись в наличии этой строки:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]